# Iam trying to populate a list in a sub view that is inside a tab view with children of a firebase database node of the log user only

Tags: database, listview, swiftui, parameter-passing, viewmodel

database structure:

I tried data binding and i tried EnviromentObject witch only give me errors i cant gets any builds with no-ones code on the net!

[database structure sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o96Y2.png)
[log in function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lycNO.png)

[view showing binding working and variable accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01NO0.png)

[sample of a View Model And how i would like to use the userID variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A688X.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.
The example should be included as code not images or links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.